# No unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users" (PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

so I'm getting an error that no unique constraint matches given keys for one of my tables. I have two tables: Users and Items, of which we have a many-to-one relationship (many items for one user). I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy to do all of this:

```
    class ItemModel(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'items'

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        title = db.Column(db.String(40))
        description = db.Column(db.String(80))
        price = db.Column(db.Float(precision=2))
        emailAddress = db.Column(db.String(40), db.ForeignKey('users.email'))

    class UserModel(db.Model):

        __tablename__ = 'users'

        id = db.Column(db.Integer)
        email = db.Column(db.String(40), primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(40))
        last_name = db.Column(db.String(40))

        items = db.relationship('ItemModel', lazy="dynamic")
```

To create the tables, I have this statement in my 'app.py':

```
    @app.before_first_request
    def create_database():
        print("Creating tables.")
        db.create_all()
```

The error is: no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table users.

I am not sure where I'm going wrong since I have a foreign key in ItemModel that matches with the primary key in UserModel. Any suggestions/tips are welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: Can u please fix the indentation of the last code `create_database()`? Or is that how it is in your code?

Comment: Sorry I meant to indent the 'def' back by one tab. I fixed it.

One interesting thing I noted is that when I removed everything except for 'email' in 'UserModel'. It worked just fine, so I'm trying to work around that problem.

Comment: Not using Flask-SQLAlchemy, but in SQL you would have to create the table `users` first - before you can create another table with a FK constraint referencing it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yeah that was actually sort of the problem - I adding the foreign key relationship but was running it through Heroku (which didn't have those relationships set) so once I set those relationships and destroyed the tables, everything began to work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got this to work - As Erwin Brandstetter mentioned above, the error occurred because you need to create the user tables first. In my case, I needed to update the user table in terms of the foreign key/primary key relationship on Postgres itself.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, so the case is closed.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of someone who ends up here but they structured their code differently, say each entity is in it's own file, check your import order before calling the `.create_all()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I like to get around the table ordering issue you're having:

```py
table_names = ['users',
               'items']

for table in table_names:
    t = db.Model.metadata.tables[table]
    t.create(bind=engine)
```